# Cannot ping outside network with these IP rules

Tags: iptables

Here is my firewall script for an internal development server.  I want to be able to get out with http/https but I only want the server accessible via ssh/http from within the internal network.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 10.1.1.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.1.1.0/24 --dport http -j ACCEPT
```

Seems to work as I expected but for some reason I cannot get seem to access the outside world.  For example:

```
super@dev0:~$ ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Since I set my default OUTPUT policy to ACCEPT, shouldn't I be able to get out without any limits?  What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allowing related packets back in. What you're seeing is not just that ping doesn't work, but that you can't even resolve DNS names. You need to do a state match for ESTABLISHED and RELATED packets:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You might as well just allow ping inbound too:

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

pings use ICMP.
Your rules with states are for TCP.
The ICMP packets goes out of your network, but are blocked with your "INPUT DROP" default policie.